How to get a model's module
I need to get the module name where a model is defined
When I ran env['res.partner']._module inside an odoo shell, the output is snailmail_account_followup, but I expected it to report base
In odoo.models.BaseModel it says this about the _module attribute:
_module = None              #: the model's module (in the Odoo sense)

Is this the expected behaviour? What's the correct way to get the module where a model is originally defined (not inherited)?

I did a bit more digging and I found the solution, so I'll document it here for future reference
Apparently,Model._module is the last module that inherited the model. To get the original module use Model._original_module instead

nice find, i will add odoo 15 and 16 to the tags, because it's the same there
